# Custom Exception.ToString() formatter

Tags: c#, strings, formatting, reflection, exception

I find the default `Exception.ToString()` formattig very difficult to read especially if there are inner exceptions involved. I guess everyone knows how it looks:

```
System.ArgumentException: This is a message. ---> UserQuery+TestException: You need to specify a valid id.
   at UserQuery.foo(Int32 id) in C:\[...]\LINQPad5\_vheqmalf\query_bkavzy.cs:line 56
   at UserQuery.Main() in C:\[...]\LINQPad5\_vheqmalf\query_bkavzy.cs:line 37
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at UserQuery.Main() in C:\[...]\LINQPad5\_vheqmalf\query_bkavzy.cs:line 41
```

So I thought I create my own formatting and later a base exception to get a better result - at least one that is more pleasing my eyes ;-)

```
TestException » You need to specify a valid id.
{
   ExtraInfo:
   [
      Bar: "Baz"
   ]
   StackTrace:
   [
      System.String UserQuery.foo(System.Int32 id) » C:\[...]\LINQPad5\_vheqmalf\query_bkavzy.cs:56
      System.Void UserQuery.Main() » C:\[...]\LINQPad5\_vheqmalf\query_bkavzy.cs:37
   ]
}
ArgumentException » This is a message.
{
   ExtraInfo:
   [
      ParamName: ""
   ]
   StackTrace:
   [
      System.Void UserQuery.Main() » C:\[...]\LINQPad5\_vheqmalf\query_bkavzy.cs:41
   ]
}
```

It's similar to json but It shouldn't be json. It should be easy to read. I'm not going to parse it.

---

To keep the implementation short I chose to use mainly dynamic objects for the formatter. It has two methods:

- `Format` that takes an exception and turns it into as string
- `GetExceptionInfos` that extracts the relevant data from each exception

`ExceptionStringFormatter` class:

```
internal class ExceptionStringFormatter : IExceptionFormatter
{
    private const string Space = " ";
    private const string CurlyBracketLeft = "{";
    private const string CurlyBracketRight = "}";
    private const string SquareBracketLeft = "[";
    private const string SquareBracketRight = "]";
    private const string RaquoSpacer = " » ";
    private const int IndentWidth = 3;

    public string Format<TException>(TException exception)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        var exceptionInfos = GetExceptionInfos(exception).Reverse();

        var exceptionString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (dynamic exceptionInfo in exceptionInfos)
        {
            exceptionString
                .Append(exceptionInfo.ExceptionType.Name).Append(RaquoSpacer)
                .Append(exceptionInfo.ExceptionMessage ?? "<Message>")
                .AppendLine();
            exceptionString.Append(CurlyBracketLeft).AppendLine();

            // format properties
            exceptionString.Append(Indent(1)).Append("ExtraInfo:").AppendLine();
            exceptionString.Append(Indent(1)).Append(SquareBracketLeft).AppendLine();
            foreach (var property in (IDictionary<string, object>)exceptionInfo.CustomProperties)
            {
                exceptionString
                    .Append(Indent(2))
                    .Append(property.Key + ": ")
                    .Append("\"" + property.Value + "\"")
                    .AppendLine();
            }
            exceptionString.Append(Indent(1)).Append(SquareBracketRight).AppendLine();

            // format stack trace
            exceptionString.Append(Indent(1)).Append("StackTrace:").AppendLine();
            exceptionString.Append(Indent(1)).Append(SquareBracketLeft).AppendLine();
            foreach (var stackFrame in exceptionInfo.StackTrace)
            {
                exceptionString
                    .Append(Indent(2))
                    .Append(stackFrame.CallerSignature).Append(RaquoSpacer)
                    .Append(stackFrame.FileName)
                    .Append(":" + stackFrame.LineNumber)
                    .AppendLine();

            }
            exceptionString.Append(Indent(1)).Append(SquareBracketRight).AppendLine();

            exceptionString.Append(CurlyBracketRight).AppendLine();
        }

        exceptionString.ToString().Dump();
        return string.Empty;
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetExceptionInfos<TException>(TException exception)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        foreach (var ex in exception.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var exceptionInfo = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
            exceptionInfo.ExceptionType = ex.GetType();
            exceptionInfo.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;

            exceptionInfo.CustomProperties = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
            foreach (var property in ex.GetCustomProperties())
            {
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)exceptionInfo.CustomProperties)[property.Key] = property.Value;
            }

            var strackTrace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
            var stackFrames = strackTrace.GetFrames();

            exceptionInfo.StackTrace = stackFrames?.Select(sf =>
            {
                var stackFrame = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
                stackFrame.CallerSignature = sf.GetMethod().Format();
                stackFrame.FileName = sf.GetFileName();
                stackFrame.LineNumber = sf.GetFileLineNumber();
                return stackFrame;
            }).ToList();

            yield return exceptionInfo;
        }
    }

    private static string Indent(int depth)
    {
        return string.Empty.PadLeft(IndentWidth * depth);
    }
}
```

There are also two helper classes.

One is the `ExceptionExtensions`. Its purpose is to enumerate the inner exceptions and to get the custom properties from each one.

```
internal static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> ExceptionPropertyNames = new HashSet<string>(
        typeof(Exception)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Select(p => p.Name));

    public static IDictionary<string, object> GetCustomProperties<TException>(this TException exception) 
        where TException : Exception
    {
        var currentExceptionProperties =
            exception.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            .Where(p => !ExceptionPropertyNames.Contains(p.Name));

        var result = currentExceptionProperties.ToDictionary(property => 
            property.Name, 
            property => property.GetValue(exception));
        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Exception> AsEnumerable(this Exception exception)
    {
        var currentException = exception;
        do
        {
            yield return currentException;
            currentException = currentException.InnerException;
        } while (currentException != null);
    }
}
```

and the other one is the `MethodSignatureFormatter` that creates method signature from method-info:

```
internal static class MethodSignatureFormatter
{
    public static string Format(this MethodBase method)
    {
        var methodInfo = method as MethodInfo;

        var signature =
            new StringBuilder()
            .Append(methodInfo.ReturnType.FullName)
            .Append(" ").Append(methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName)
            .Append(".").Append(methodInfo.Name)
            .Append("(")
            .Append(string.Join(", ", methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => 
                p.ParameterType.FullName + " " + p.Name)))
            .Append(")");

        return signature.ToString();
    }
}
```

Base exception with custom formatting:

```
public abstract class FormattableException : Exception
{
    protected FormattableException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) { }

    protected FormattableException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public IExceptionFormatter Formatter { get; set; } = new ExceptionStringFormatter();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Formatter?.Format(this) ?? base.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

Demo:

```
void Main()
{

    try
    {
        try
        {
            foo(9);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("This is a message.", ex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("-");
        Console.WriteLine(new ExceptionStringFormatter().Format(ex));
    }
}

string foo(int id)
{
    throw new TestException("You need to specify a valid id.") { Bar = "Baz" };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private const string Space = " ";
```

There's little point in storing this in a variable: it's never going to change anyway and you're not clarifying any of the intent. I'm fully aware that  is a space and `{` is a left curly bracket.

---

Using `dynamic` is a very, very expensive action. By defaulting to it everywhere instead of using an intermediate type you're incurring heavy costs on yourself.

---

```
.Append(exceptionInfo.ExceptionMessage ?? "<Message>")
```

I'm not sure if `<Message>` is a default I'd like to see. It makes it feel as if something wasn't parsed correctly -- perhaps you can just leave it empty or give it an actual description like "No message found"?

---

```
internal class ExceptionStringFormatter : IExceptionFormatter
```

It has no instance fields so you might as well make it a static class with static members. That way you don't have to create a new object every time you want to format an exception string.

---

```
exceptionString.ToString().Dump();
return string.Empty;
```

Testing remnant?

---

```
var exceptionInfo = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
```

Might as well just write

```
dynamic exceptionInfo = new ExpandoObject();
```

---

```
AsEnumerable(this Exception exception)
```

Seems like a questionable name for what it does. Perhaps something like `GetInnerExceptions()` is more appropriate considering that's what it is actually implemented as and not just a projection of one exception to a list of exceptions.

---

```
var methodInfo = method as MethodInfo;
```

Use a direct cast or perform a `null` check. Right now you're just using the result directly which could mean you get a `NullReferenceException` -- a `ClassCastException` would be much more helpful in identifying the issue.

---

Comment: Ooops, yes `.Dump()` shouldn't be there (copy&paste from linqpad). I picked dynamics because exceptions themselves are very time consuming and actually shouldn't occur very often so I just thought a little bit of dynamics won't hurt it any further. As to `new ExpandoObject() as dynamic` - I just like `var` on the left side :-) As far as the other suggestions are concerned I agree and will definitely correct them ;-]