# Generating unique ID of an exception

Tags: c#, exception, hashcode

For classifying error reports, I need to generate an ID from an exception. That ID should be

- (more or less) unique
- a short alpha numeric string
- equal for equivalent exceptions (even on different systems)

The following code seems to do the job:

```
    public static string GetExceptionID(this Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex == null) return "0000";

        int hash = 31;
        var innerException = ex;
        while (innerException != null)
        {
            hash ^= GetHash(innerException.GetType().ToString());

            hash ^= innerException.StackTrace
                                  .Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                  // If *.pdb file is provided, the file and line no. (e.g. "... in C:\Path...") is part of the stacktrace.
                                  // The next line cutting off that part
                                  .Select(line => line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(" in ") < 0 ? line.Length : line.IndexOf(" in ")))
                                  .Aggregate(31, (currentHash, val) => currentHash ^= val.GetHash());

            innerException = innerException.InnerException;
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(hash))
            .Replace('+', 'P')
            .Replace('-', 'M')
            .Replace("=", "")
            .ToUpper();
    }

    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function
    private static int GetHash(this string str)
    {
        if (str == null) return 1;

        int hash = 31;
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                hash += c;
                hash += hash << 10;
                hash ^= hash >> 6;
            }
        }

        hash += hash << 3;
        hash ^= hash >> 11;
        hash += hash << 15;

        return hash;
    }
```

Do you see any problems with the code?

Comment: Some create a unique ID such as SQLexception has Number

Comment: @Paparazzi: Yes, that's right... however, I need a solution that works with all kinds of exceptions ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Stack trace

I think you shouldn't work with the stack string but retrieve the stack and go through each frame yourself. I find it would make the analysis more reliable and you could get the information you need without extracting it from the string because you would have direct access to each part.

```
private static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetStackTrace(this Exception exception)
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace(exception, true);
    var stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
    var result = stackFrames?.Select(sf => new
    {
        Caller = (sf.GetMethod() as MethodInfo)?.ToShortString() ?? string.Empty,
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(sf.GetFileName()),
        LineNumber = sf.GetFileLineNumber(),
    });
}
```

*This snippet comes from my [Exception prettyfier](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147768/exceptionprettifier-for-prettier-exception-strings).*

---

## Other suggestions

It would be a good idea to split this method into three or four methods.

- the first one gets you the information you need from the stack - you could implement it either based on the string or on the raw stack trace
- the second one would encode the data as `Base64String`
- the third and last one would *clean-up* or encode the string generated by the second one
- the fourth could be a helper encapsulating the three other methods

Example:

```
var ex.ToExceptionId()
```

where

```
public static string ToExceptionId(this Exception ex)
{
    return ex.GetStackTrace().ToBase64String().EncodeBase64String();
}
```

Now you can test and maintain each part of the exception id creation separately.

Comment: Personally, I would never use `dynamic` just to avoid creating a real type as you do.  It defeats the purpose of a statically typed language for no real gain.  Also, you use the null coalescing operator on `stackFrames`, storing it in `result` (which you presumably had intended to actually return) -- that means if `GetFrames()` returns null, you'll return a null enumerable, which is bad form.  But totally agree with generating the stack trace yourself -- came as a surprise to me to see in BugSnag that stack traces are localized!  That "at" in front of each line will be in the user's language!

Comment: @KirkWoll your're right about the `null` enumerable, I should add a  `?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()` there. You can review my original question where I use it if you like :-)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is a good idea to use the StackTrace class instead of parsing the stack trace as string! I've changed my implementation according to your suggestion ;)

Comment: It turns out, that the solution with `StackTrace` does not work in my case, because the exceptions, I am working with, may be serialized/deserialized (BinaryFormatter). The serialization process drop the`TargetSite` property from the Exception object. Supposably, that property is requried for the `StackTrace` class to...

Comment: @JanDotNet that's interesting. Can you create a simple example to reproduce this and post a link to pastebin or something? I was always wondering how the `TargetSite` works. This sounds like a good opportunity and maybe I can use it to improve my formatter :-D

Comment: Here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DUUdFe (just copy&past to Linqpad ;))

Comment: @JanDotNet thx. I see this is a tough nut and I give up ;-) In this case using the `StackTrace` isn't of much help, indeed. As the exception string might be localized, using a regex for finding paths could be better then the `in` string.

Comment: hmm.. I am not able to generate a localized stack trace. I tried to set the current thread's CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture to "de-DE" and I changed the system's display language to german. But the stacktrace is still localized in english!

Comment: @KirkWoll I think we need your help. Do you know how to create a localized stack trace?

Comment: @JanDotNet look here at the source code. It really gets the _at_ and _in_ from some resource https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/stacktrace.cs,f4bbb1fa2df8ea1f but I have no idea how to change it. Maybe it works only if the entire .net is in a different language.

Comment: Hmm, what sort of app is this?  A Windows app where it could be anywhere?  In our app, we definitely get stack traces reported to BugSnag with the words localized to the user's language.  So I'm a bit surprised that you aren't getting localized stack traces.  However, if it's *always* English for you, then it's pretty straightforward to just parse it as you had originally intended and presume "at".  Finally, out of curiosity, why isn't it being serialized in the first place?  Are you using something like WCF?

Comment: (oops, meant to ask, "why _is_ it being serialized i the first place?")

Comment: according to [this posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272323/how-to-completely-avoid-localized-net-exception-messages), it seems that the localized resources are part of the .net language pack which can be installed separately.